# How to subclass pandas-dataframe to have certain column names?

Tags: python, pandas

Often times functions except a passed dataframe to have certain column names, which can be checked like this:

```
def current_function(df: pd.DataFrame):
    expected_column_names =  {"country", "population", "city"}
    assert set(df.columns).issubset(expected_column_names)
    print(df.country)
```

However, if multiple functions use such a dataframe, it's nicer to simply create a new class:

```
class SubclassedDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    expected_column_names = {"country", "population", "city"}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(SubclassedDataFrame, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        assert set(self.columns).issubset(self.expected_column_names)

    @property
    def country(self):
        return self.loc[:,"country"]


def desired_function(df: SubclassedDataFrame):
    print(df.country)
```

Questions:

- Multiple columns require multiple property-decorated methods. Can we simplify this?
- Is there an even more straightforward way to achieve such a subclass?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear. You want any subclassed dataframe to have _at least_ those 3 columns or _only_ those 3? Also do you expect to handle things like `rename` and `drop` which could potentially remove or change those columns?

Comment: Also is there a reason you're making a `@property` for `country` when [Attribute access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access) already makes `df.country` a valid operation? Or is this just a general example?

Comment: @HenryEcker: The `@property` decorator would be nice to let IDEs know of existing members. `rename` and `drop` don't have to be supported, no. The dataframe should have *at least* the expected columns (though to have exactly those would probably not be any more difficult, or?)